# Load Pillow image as texture in pyglet

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyglet

## Problem

I am trying to load a Pillow image as a Pyglet texture using the following code:

```
pixels = pillow_image.convert("L").tobytes()
width, height = pillow_image.size

image = pyglet.image.ImageData(width, height, "L", pixels, pitch=width)
image = image.get_texture().get_transform(flip_y=True)
```

It gives me the following error message:

```
  image = image.get_texture().get_transform(flip_y=True)
  File "/home/home_dir/.local/share/virtualenvs//app/-r0DkEahp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 692, in get_texture
    self._current_texture = self.create_texture(Texture, rectangle)
  File "/home/home_dir/.local/share/virtualenvs//app/-r0DkEahp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 681, in create_texture
    texture = cls.create(self.width, self.height, GL_TEXTURE_2D, internalformat)
  File "/home/home_dir/.local/share/virtualenvs//app/-r0DkEahp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 1260, in create
    glTexImage2D(target, 0,
  File "/home/home_dir/.local/share/virtualenvs//app/-r0DkEahp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/gl/lib.py", line 79, in errcheck
    raise GLException(f'(0x{error}): {msg}')
pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: (0x1281): Invalid value. A numeric argument is out of range.
```

I tried resizing the image since I read that there is a size limit on textures, but no luck.

## Minimum reproducible example

Consider the following image:

[image: Gravatar]

Download this image and call it "gravatar.png". Then the following code reproduces the issue with the latest pyglet version:

```
import pyglet
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("/path/to/gravatar.png").convert("L")
width, height = im.size

image = pyglet.image.ImageData(width, height, "L", im.tobytes(), pitch=width)
image = image.get_texture().get_transform(flip_y=True)
```

## Insights so far

I have realized that the code I've posted here works for 1.5.x versions of pyglet but it doesn't work for 2.x versions of pyglet. This explains why it worked before, since I originally wrote the code before the first 2.x release.

## Question

Given the insight that it works for 1.5.x versions of pyglet, my question is now how to get it to work in 2.x versions of pyglet.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] please, with `import` statements and a representative image that causes the error?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have update the question. I also added a note about a work-around that I found.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using your example and it seems to work fine without error on Windows 10. Pyglet 2.0.5.

I get this result after that then saving it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for testing the code. Weird that it doesn’t work for me.

Comment: Make sure your pyglet is the latest version, should be on 2.0.5